# Memory leaks from XCode instruments showing Assembly code

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am using the **Instruments** through **XCode 6.4 (iOS 8.3, Swift 1.2)** profiling to find **memory-leaks** in my app. This is what I find:

[image]

When I click on any of this, and click on the stack-trace on the right hand pane, I see that its coming from the `init()` of some of my implemented `UIViewControllers`. Eg. `MyViewController.init()`. However, I have not implemented init for any view controller.

When I double click that line, it shows assembly-code as details. 

Eg.
`+0x27b callq               "DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSendSuper2"`

All the tutorials about finding memory leaks through Xcode say that I would find the line of code in Xcode, but thats not happening. How do I find the cause so that I can fix these leaks?